# Serialize Node Graph to integer

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to serialize a node graph into an integer, in a way that it is recoverable? For example:

```
node   weight node

*x*    3      *y*

*y*    2      *z*

*z*    5      *y*
```

Serialize into, say, 132223352. But maintaining each node independent so another graph can be matched as a sub-graph, `152232 is contained in 132223352`.

Comment: Sure.  Encode digits $0$ through $9$ as $10$ through $19$.  Use the remaining two-digit numbers to encode whatever punctuation you like... parentheses and commas will suffice to serialize arbitrary tuples, which is plenty to encode a graph.

Comment: Whatever you can represent in a file on a computer disk can be though of as a big number in 256-ary system. However, these serializations usually won't have properties like matching subgraphs as substrings. One important detail is the order of vertices, with fixed order things get much easier. Take a look at [canonical forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form) and [graph canonization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization).

Answer (score 0):

As talked about in the comments, you've stumbled on the difficult problem of [graph canonization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization) and how to present graphs in useful ways. I think finding an *efficient* answer to your question is really hard.